# What is the correct notation for summation not including certain terms?

Tags: summation, notation

I want to represent a summation of (say) n terms, but not include (say) the j-th term. Do I represent it like $$\sum_{i=1,i\not=j}^\infty f_i(t) = g(t)$$
Is there any other way? Also, what if there are a number of such j but are random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Roddy MacPhee, you could write
$$ \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\not\in A}}^{\infty} a_i, $$
where $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is the set of indices that you wish to exclude  (note the use of the `\substack` command; this is perhaps easier to read).  It would also be reasonable to write
$$ \sum_{i\in I} a_i, $$
where $I$ is the set of indices that you wish to sum over.  Note that $I$ can be any set, and needn't be the natural numbers (though if $I$ is uncountable, you might run into trouble).    For example, we could write
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{i} a_{ij}
= \sum_{\substack{i,j\in\mathbb{N} \\ 1 \le j \le i \le \infty}} a_{ij}.
$$
I'm not sure that you would want to, but you could.  ;)

I would also suggest that it is generally poor practice to not indicate *in the notation* how the terms being summed depend on the index of summation.  When you write
$$ \sum_{i\in I} f(t), $$
do you mean
$$ \sum_{i\in I} f_i(t),
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\sum_{i\in I} f(t_i)?$$
That is, do the functions depend on $i$, or do the arguments of the function depend on $i$?  Or is something else going on?  You did indicate in your explanation that there is an $i$ in there somewhere, but it is vastly easier to read if the dependence is included in the notation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll edit the question with regards to the dependency on $i$.

Answer (score 2):

you could define a set first (say A) containing the j values you don't want, and then use:

$\sum_\limits{i=1,i\notin A}^\infty f(t)=g(t)$